# sequelize: delete cascade with belongsToMany association

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js

In the following simple case:
- product can have many images
- images can have many products
I try to use delete cascade to remove related images when I delete a product.

```
var product = sequelize.define('product', {
    name: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
});

var image = sequelize.define('image', {
    name: Sequelize.DataTypes.STRING,
});

// setup relations
image.belongsToMany(product, {
    through: 'productImage',
    onDelete: 'cascade',
});

product.belongsToMany(image, {
    through: 'productImage',
    onDelete: 'cascade',
});

// create tables
await sequelize.drop({ force: true });
await sequelize.sync();

// create some data
await product.create({
    name: 'product1',
    images: [
        { name: 'image1' },
        { name: 'image2' },
    ]
},{
    include: [{ model: image }]
});

// find and delete the product
var prod = await product.findById(1);
await prod.destroy();
```

Here, product is deleted, productImage relations are deleted, but images are still here.
How to tell sequelize to also delete images when nothing refers them any more ?

Comment: can you check your database's `on delete` option?

Comment: it it something available through the sequelize configuration ?